# Присваивание переменным в Python значения None

Tags: python

Является ли хорошим тоном присваивание переменным в Python значения None? Допустим, у меня есть переменная n, в которую я хочу занести какое-то значение из списка k, путём перебора циклом и проверки условия. Но я хочу и дальше использовать переменную n в своей программе. Как я знаю, в Python при объявлении переменной обязательна инициализация, но я не знаю каким значением её инициализировать. Правильна ли такая практика?

Comment: Приведите пример, в котором вы хотите это использовать

Comment: @dIm0n я привёл мысленный пример.

Comment: Хороший пример кода лучше тысячи слов 

Comment: Присваивание переменной None не спасет вас от того, что вы забудете ей присвоить какое-то нормальное значение. Вместо нормальной ошибки "попытка чтения из неинициализированной переменной", вы получите какую-то другую ошибку, или просто выведется None там где не должно было выводиться.

Comment: @insolor так может предложите решение данной проблемы?)

Comment: Да, использовать IDE, например PyCharm. PyCharm покажет вам где вы пытаетесь прочитать не используемую переменную, до запуска кода.

Comment: @insolor нет, не касаемо IDE, а касаемо самого языка.

Comment: Без IDE - никак, максимум что можно посоветовать - "внимательней будь!" В любом языке при попытке чтения из неинициализированной или несуществующей переменной в лучшем случае вы получите ошибку (в худшем случае - из переменной будет прочитан мусор). Выход - использовать дополнительные инструменты, которые могут перенять часть "внимательности" на себя.

Comment: @insolor в Python нельзя объявить переменную без её инициализации.

Comment: 1 - обычно это и не требуется. 2 - можно написать имя переменной с ее предполагаемым типом после двоеточия, и все (вроде бы начиная с Python 3.6 это работает), опять же проверка типа перекладывается на отдельные инструменты, например IDE или mypy.

Comment: Допустим я бы назвал переменную не n, а как-то длинней; и не использовал ее неявным образом где-то далеко с разными целями. Практически все переменные примут свое значение сразу. Смотрите List Comprehension. И да, пример кода бы, может правда нужно...

Comment: В целом - да, в питоне None именно для подобных вещей и нужен.

Comment: @Xander да, я тоже к этому пришёл)
И вот хотел узнать: правильно ли так делать? А то может где по рукам за такое дадут) В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: @vanyavanya, если мне действительно надо, я сделаю так , как вы пишите. Вопрос в том, что надо оно будет в 0-5% случаев.

Comment: @insolor, *Без IDE - никак*. например, pylint отлично находит использование неинициализированной переменной. анализатор кода, встроенный в ide, вряд ли чем-то принципиально отличается от [уже имеющихся анализаторов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284448/4827341).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да, согласен, правильнее было бы написать "без дополнительных инструментов, только средствами интерпретатора, на данный момент - никак"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Решил написать ответ, потому что все-таки есть случаи, когда инициализация переменных значением `None` имеет смысл.*

> Как я знаю, в Python при объявлении переменной обязательна инициализация...

Начиная с Python 3.6 можно объявлять переменные с аннотацией типа без инициализации:

```
some_var: SomeType
```

Но тогда для проверки "инициализированности" переменной (для локальной или глобальной переменной, не поля класса) придется использовать конструкцию `'some_var' in locals()` или `'some_var' in globals()`, что не очень красиво, ИМХО (вообще практически никогда не стоит использовать `locals()` и `globals()`). Если проверять заполненность переменной не нужно, то это неплохой вариант (но объявление с инициализацией лучше).

Для проверки полей класса можно использовать `hasattr`, что на мой взгляд вполне допустимо (см. п.3 ниже).

В целом нет никаких правил, запрещающих инициализировать переменную значением `None`. Типичные варианты использования:

1. Начальное значение переменной в которую будет будет записано одно из значений из последовательности при проходе по ней циклом. Типичный пример - начальное значение для максимума/минимума последовательности по какому-то критерию (можно конечно брать значение первого элемента за минимум/максимум, но тогда сначала нужно проверить, что последовательность не пустая)
2. Начальное/неопределенное состояние для [конечного автомата](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82)
3. Начальные значения при "объявлении" полей объекта внутри метода `__init__`. Например PyCharm фактически требует, чтобы все поля объекта были инициализированы внутри `__init__` (попытку записи в поле не объявленное внутри `__init__` PyCharm выделяет как предупреждение). Можно было бы на это правило и забить (отключить в настройках), но в этом есть смысл - удобно, когда все поля объекта объявлены в одном месте.

   В этом случае также имеет смысл аннотацией показывать предполагаемый
   тип поля:

   ```
   class SomeClass:
       def __init__(self):
           # >= Python 3.6
           self.a: int = None

           # < Python 3.6
           self.b = None  # type: int
   ```

   Также начиная с Python 3.6 поля можно объявлять с аннотацией типа просто как `self.a: int` без инициализации, инициализированность поля в этом случае можно проверять с помощью `hasattr(self, 'a')` (не факт что это хороший вариант, я бы все-таки использовал вариант с инициализацией `None`).

Думаю, это не все варианты, возможно что-то забыл.

Также нужно понимать, что инициализация переменной значением `None` "на всякий случай" не убережет вас от невнимательности, и вместо падения программы с исключением `NameError` или `AttributeError` у вас может вылезти значение `None` там где оно совсем не ожидалось, и возможно будет сложнее отловить откуда оно взялось, чем в случае выбрасывания исключения (см. [принцип Fail Fast](https://habr.com/ru/post/218325/)). Я бы рекомендовал по возможности инициализировать переменные вменяемыми значениями, а не `None`.

Comment: да, первый пример про max и min в точку, т.к. именно при прохождении списка в цикле использовал подобное, лишь хотел удостовериться, что всё правильно. Спасибо:)